# Magento2 installation trouble admin login

Tags: php, magento2

magento2 I'm have empty response on admin but not get error... Php error log empty, debug log empty in magento and system log, mode developer, and in apache2 config LogLevel debug....
in browser the error show when

[image: http://ibin.co/2UyuVomcuD6d]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The connection was reset` Apache message is a PHP fault.
It may be because of using an unstable PHP version like PHP 7.0.x.

Comment: I'm use php 5.5.* version and you correct answer apache is down by segmentation fault [Thu Jan 28 10:38:37.240830 2016] [core:notice] [pid 18483] AH00051: child pid 19340 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache. You can help me resolve the trouble. sorry for my English.

Comment: Try to use another PHP version: I recommend the latest PHP 5.6.x.

Comment: Yes I fink this is intl extensions get fault.